# Laravel and jQuery file upload

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, file-upload

Im trying to add jQuery file upload plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin to my site and im using Laravel framework.

This is in my view:

```
            {{ Form::open(['action' => 'MyController@uploadGallery'])}}

                {{ Form::text('name')}} <br><br>

                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="theme-admin/fileupload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
                <script src="theme-admin/fileupload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
                <script src="theme-admin/fileupload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

                <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('#fileupload').fileupload({

                        url: '/gallery',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        done: function (e, data) {
                            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                            });
                        },

                        progressall: function (e, data) {
                            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                            $('#progress .bar').css(
                                'width',
                                progress + '%');
                        }

                    });

                });
                </script>

                <br>

                <input type="submit">

            {{ Form::close() }}

            <div id="progress">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
            </div>
```

After selecting images some javascript is calling path: `*website*/server/php` where is index.php, but Laravel is redirecting that path, returning error: `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` . I've tryed to add new route and copypaste script in index.php to MyController@serverphp method, but the same error occured:

```
Route::get('server/php', array('as' => 'serverphp', 'uses' => 'MyController@serverphp'));
```

What should I do now?

Comment: From looking at the file upload js, you should be sending images to /gallery URL. If something else is redirecting the user to index.php, find out what that part is and stop it from redirecting to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, might not be the exact same problem, but on the project I'm working one, there was a rule on .htaccess to redirect urls based on trailing slashes. That might got in conflict with the jquery upload redirect rule. As soon as I removed that rule everything worked fine.

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I realized that it should had been something related to .htaccess because I just installed the default example on my local computer and it worked. When I upload the default example to the server it didn't work. It got the redirect loop. Thus, it was probably a server configuration issue.